# Make the Category be the Namespace in nUnit

Tags: c#, nunit

I have a few hundred of test fixtures in C#, I want to add a Category to each, and I want each Category to be the namespace, I don't want to hardcode the Namespace string in each of them.

Maybe something like this:

```
[Category(NamespaceTitle)]
```

Then I can add that line to all of our fixtures, is this possible at all?

Comment: I don't believe this is currently possible. Can you explain why you want to do this - maybe there's another solution that would work?

Comment: If you want to add the category, so you can run tests one namespace at a time, are you aware you can filter by namespace on the nunit3-console.exe command line?

Comment: Actually - I think this is probably possible with a custom attribute. But maybe there's a better solution than adding a custom attribute to every TestFixture, depending on what you're aiming to do. =)

Comment: Thank you all, we decided not to go down this route, as @Chris mentioned, we can filter by namespace in the console.